# Not able to access access_token value using QueryString (Google OAuth 2.0)

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm not able to fetch the `access_token` value from a QueryString in ASP.Net (C#).

Google is sending the authorization token, but I am not able to capture the token value by using

1. QueryString (getting null)
2. splitting string (not getting full url)

The RedirectUrl is: `http://www.onfrnz.com/auth.aspx`

```
http://www.onfrnz.com/auth.aspx#state=/profile
    &access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
    &token_type=Bearer
    &expires_in=3600
```

Please help me on this. I don't want to use a library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code for how you tried to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access a hash fragment value in server-side code.  The hash fragment value (after the # in the URL), does not get sent from the web browser to the web server, and thus will not be accessible in server-side code.

When you initially kick off the OAuth flow, you're likely using:

```
&response_type=token
```

This indicates you want to use the flow for client-side (JavaScript) applications (called the "implicit" flow in the spec).

Instead, you should be using:

```
&response_type=code
```

This will return an authorization `code` value in the query parameter, which you should be able to retrieve using your .NET code, and then exchange for an access token by making a server-to-server request to Google.

More information on Google's OAuth 2.0 flow for web server applications (authorization code flow) is available here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Thanks for the response !! I have fixed it using javascript .